# "Over half" and "one half": plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, subject-verb-agreement

> 1. **Over half** of the domestic flights **were** delayed because of bad weather condition.

Is this correct to use "were" here?

What if "one half" is used instead of "over half"?

> 2. **One half** of the domestic flights **were/was** delayed because of bad weather condition.

Which is correct for #2, "were" or "was"?

What if we remove the definite article "the"? Does it affect the use of plural/singular verb?

> 3. Over half of **domestic** flights **were** delayed because of bad weather condition.

Answer (score 3):

Half is half of one (or for that sake whatever number you have), so no need to include 'one' there. About singular/plural verb, you are talking about *more than one flight*, so it takes 'were'. Moreover, putting 'the' here ensures that you are specific about domestic flights that got delayed because of the weather condition.

---

'half of the' or 'half of' makes a separate (and also good) question though.

Comment: Can you please explain difference b/w "half of the" and "half of"?

Comment: As I said, it makes a good question. Ask it separately. I'll be 'on' for it! :)

Comment: OK now you can answer as I ask it in a separate question. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54075/half-of-the-vs-half-of/54084#54084

Answer (score 2):

In all those cases you want "were" because the subject of the sentence is not "half" it's *flights*. Here "half" modifies "flights" by telling you the portion of them.

> Flights were delayed.

Is the core of the sentence. You then add the portion and reason on top of that.

Consider:

> Half of the apple*s* **were** rotten.
>
> Half of the apple **was** rotten.

There is a special exception for the quantity *one* though:

> One of the apple*s* **was** rotten.

The one actually makes the whole phrase singular despite "apples" being plural. Logically we *must* be talking about a single apple. But in:

> One half of the apple*s* **were** rotten.

"One" modifies "*half*", not "apples".